# Implementation a variation of `Optional.or()` method

Tags: java, option-type, supplier

I am currently learning about the functionalities of the Optional class, and I am trying to build a simplified version of the Optional class. I was able to code `ifPresent()`, `filter()`, `of()`, `map()` and so on. However, I am currently stuck with the implementing `or()`.

I know that `or()` have the signature `Optional<T> or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier)`. However, my implementation assumed that I can access the contents of the Optional. As show below:

```
class Optional<T> {
    private final T item;
    ...

    Optional<T> or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier) {
        if (this.item == null) {
            T item = supplier.get().item;
            return Maybe.<T>of(item);
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `T item = supplier.get().item` would throw an error saying that `.item` is inaccessible due to it being private. How am I able to access the `item` without causing this error?

Comment: You first would have to check whether the `Optional` returned by `supplier` is present or not. Only then could you unwrap the optional to access the element

Comment: I'd say it should be `T item = supplier.get().get();`. The first `get()` is the one in `Supplier` which returns the optional, the second `get()` is the one in `Optional` and might be replaced by `orElse(someDefaultValue)`. Of course if your `Maybe` has a method `of(Optional<T>)` then just use `return Maybe.of(supplier.get());`.

Comment: Shouldn't the signature of your method be `Maybe<T> or(Supplier<? extends Maybe<? extends T>> supplier)`? In that case if your Maybe is empty you should just `return supplier.get();`.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the class name. I have corrected it.

Comment: There’s still a spurious `MayBe` in your `Optional` type. And I suppose, `thing` should be `item`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to recall that you can not access a `private` field through an instance of a subtype, even though assigning the subtype reference to a variable of the current type, which allows the access, is possible without cast.

So if you have

```java
public class ClassWithPrivateField {
    private String field;
  
    static class Subclass extends ClassWithPrivateField {}
  
    void someMethod(Subclass obj) {
        String s = obj.field; // does not work, you can't access field through Subclass
    }
}
```

you may write

```java
public class ClassWithPrivateField {
    private String field;
  
    static class Subclass extends ClassWithPrivateField {}
  
    void someMethod(Subclass obj) {
        ClassWithPrivateField withBroaderType = obj; // always works
        String s = withBroaderType.field; // now, no problem to access field
    }
}
```

Now to your more complicated generic variant. If you have

```java
public class Optional<T> {
    private final T item;
  
    private Optional(T t) {
      item = t;
    }
  
    Optional<T> or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier) {
        if(this.item == null) {
            T item = supplier.get().item;
            return Optional.of(item);
        }
        else return this;
    }
  
    private static <T> Optional<T> of(T item2) {
      return new Optional<>(item2);
    }
}
```

the access to `item` is rejected by the compiler because the type returned by the supplier is `? extends Optional<? extends T>` which is a *subtype of* `Optional<? extends T>`, just the same way as `Subclass` is a subtype of `ClassWithPrivateField`.

You can fix the issue the same way, by introducing a variable:

```java
public class Optional<T> {
    private final T item;
  
    private Optional(T t) {
      item = t;
    }
  
    Optional<T> or(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier) {
        if(this.item == null) {
            Optional<? extends T> optional = supplier.get(); // valid assignment
            T item = optional.item; // valid access
            return Optional.of(item);
        }
        else return this;
    }
  
    private static <T> Optional<T> of(T item2) {
      return new Optional<>(item2);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could insert a type cast to `Optional<? extends T>` like

```java
T item = ((Optional<? extends T>)supplier.get()).item;
```

but I would prefer the variant with a variable as it immediately shows to the reader that the assignment (without a cast) is a valid type transition which can never fail. The type cast can not fail either and is a no-op at runtime, but its syntax is indistinguishable from type casts performing a runtime check that could fail.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

```
    T item = supplier.get().item;
    return Maybe.<T>of(item);
```

with

```
    return (Optional<T>)supplier.get();
```

Comment: You need to add a cast to `Optional<T>` for that to work. The return type of `supplier.get()` is `Optional<? extends T>`

Comment: But this type cast will generate an “unchecked” warning.

Comment: @Holger yes. Just ignore it. It is result of pure java design, there is nothing you can do about it.