# Why can't I access a private (nestmate) class member via generics?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have something equivalent to this:

```
class Main {
    public static class Data {
        private void foo() {}
    }
    
    public <D extends Data> D process(D data) {
        data.foo();
        return data;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

> *The method foo() from the type Main.Data is not visible*

I don't see why this shouldn't work. It compiles fine if I don't use generics in `process`:

```
    public Data process(Data data) {
        data.foo();
        return data;
    }
```

I want to use generics here so I can keep a fluent interface that returns the exact subclass of Data that is passed in, but I also want to keep Data's base members private to the outer class.

Why is this happening and what are my options?

Comment: A simple workaround is to assign it to a local `Data` variable.

Comment: [Same as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320648/2711488), `D` is a subtype of `Data` and you can’t access a `private` member through a subtype reference. The fact that this is a nested class, is a red herring; it would be the same if the `process` method was inside the `Data` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though you dont use generics , this problem will be there. D is not a "Data" for compiler , it is some other type which extends "Data".

```
public class Main {

    public static class Data {
        private void foo() {}
    }
    
    public static class DataX extends Data
    {
        
    }  


    public DataX process(DataX data) {
        data.foo();  // will not be compiled because foo() has private access
        return data;
    }
}
```

as a solution you can directly cast it to a local variable of type `Data` , or you can do it in tricky way (same thing, suits if `process` method has some logic inside)  like this.

```
public class Main {

    public static class Data {
        private void foo() {}
    }

    public <D extends Data> D process(D data) {
        internalProcess(data);
        return data;
    }
    
    private void internalProcess(Data data)
    {
        data.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compile error is because even subclasses do not have direct access to `private` members. Your generic method declares `D` as a subclass of `Data`, thus it does not have access to `foo` which is `private`. This is outlined in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

The reason why you can do this without generics is because whilst `foo` is `private`, it is visible at the `class` level and thus `Data` and `Main`. If the `Data` class declaration was separate (file or package) then `Main` would not have access either.

That said, a simple solution is to assign to a local variable as per [shmosel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398168/why-cant-i-access-a-private-nestmate-class-member-via-generics/74398257#comment131339001_74398168):

```java
public <D extends Data> D process(D data) {
    Data d = data;
    d.foo();
    return data;
}
```

We could also make this more concise by using casting:

```java
((Data) data).foo();
```

In either case, this is type safe because `D` is a type of `Data` (as declared in the method signature) so we can treat it as such, and we don't break the requirement to keep the member `private`.

Alternatively, if we don't strictly require the members to be `private`, we could declare them `protected` or *package private* (no modifier).